# using stored procedure with WCF service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, stored-procedures

I am working WCF web service. I have created WCF service library. I have a stored procedure with three parameters. I want to use this stored procedure with an operation contract. I want to return a collection of DataContract or dataset ( whatever is better) from this operation contract. How can I use stored procedure with WCF service operation contract?

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Comment: You just need to take in the three parameters in your service method that you need for calling the stored procedure - and then convert the output of the stored procedure into .NET objects and return a list (or array) of those objects.

Comment: @marc_s any sample or link ?